# Wordpress Login Box horizontal at the top.

Tags: login

Okay so I learned how to add the wordpress login box to the site. I don't want the box style in sidebar but more of horizontal box in the top of the page under the menu in horizontal way.

Are there any pointers for going with this route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`wp_login_form()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_login_form/) and set the `p` elements per CSS inline, so they can sit side by side:

```css
#loginform p
{
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to control the textarea width so that it take less space?

Comment: There is no `textarea`. You can style each input field separately, they have IDs.